# Scrollview - TextView limits in terms of numbers of lines

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, limit

My app is doing logging and the user could have it run for days. In this case I could end out having 100k lines of text that you could scroll through.

This doesn't seem reasonnable. I should see some memory limits. How many lines of text would you maintain at max?

Can you have a rolling textview which would maintain the last 1k lines of text? Should I do it with only a textviewwith a maxlines of 1k and scrollbar?

At the moment I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.narb.log.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the log number"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would set the max lines to 100 and would add a read more option at the end of the Text and when the user clicks that, I would set max lines to textview.maxlines + 100 and would hide the read more when there no more text to show.